# Proof Verification About Sequence Limits

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

I had work to hand in which included the following question

> Let $(a_n), (b_n)$ satisfy $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_nb_n=1$.
>
> Proof that if for all $n$, $0\leq a_n,b_n \leq 1$ then
>    $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_n=1$.

My solution which I handed in was pretty straightfoward- showing easily that $a_nb_n\leq a_n\leq 1$ and the same for $b_n$. Then I used the squeeze theorem to show their limits are $1$.

However, people (also the teachers who assisted some students) started talking about partial limits and Bolzano–Weierstrass which really makes my dbout my solution's validness, which I seek here from you at the moment.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** See my comment below

Comment: Your argument is fine, and probably the easiest. One *can* use the B-W theorem to prove the result, but it takes a bit more work.

Comment: My course's guy whose responsible for teaching and creating the tests just mailed me it's okay! I would like to see the B-W solution however for general knowledge if someone could write it down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your argument is fine and is the easiest one that occurs to me.

An argument using the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem is also possible, though it takes a bit more work. Suppose that $\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ does not converge to $1$. Then there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $M=\{n\in\Bbb N:a_n\le 1-\epsilon\}$ is infinite. The subsequence $\langle a_n:n\in M\rangle$ is bounded, so by the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem it has a convergent subsequence: there is an infinite $M_0\subseteq M$ such that $\langle a_n:n\in M_0\rangle$ converges, say to $\ell$; clearly $\ell\le 1-\epsilon$, since $a_n\le 1-\epsilon$ for each $n\in M_0$. But $\langle a_nb_n:n\in M_0\rangle$ converges to $1$, so $\langle b_n:n\in M_0\rangle$ converges to $\frac{1}{\ell}>1$, which is impossible, since $b_n\le 1$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. This contradiction shows that $\lim_na_n=1$, and it follows immediately that $\lim_nb_n=1$ as well.